# Execution stops after the instantiation of a variable with a scanner input

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I'm doing internships with a small project that asks the user to select a category of expenses, to later request quantities that are stored in a ArrayList and finally the amount of the total expenses of that category is printed on the screen. The problem comes at the moment in which I associate the variable 'quantity' with a Scanner entry, at that moment the execution thread remains in Execution and it does not return any type of error.

```
package gestioneconomica;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    /**
     *
     * @author Robin
     */
     class Gastos {
        //Declaración de los tipos de gastos organizados en ArrayList()  

        ArrayList<Double> taberna=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Double> tPublico=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Double> alimentacion=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Double> formacion=new ArrayList<>();
        //Declaración e inicialización de la suma de los valores de cada ArrayList()
        double sumTaberna=0.0;
        double sumTPublico=0.0;
        double sumAlimentacion=0.0;
        double sumFormacion=0.0;

        //Instanciación del objeto 'sc' de la clase Scanner
        Scanner sd=new Scanner(System.in);
    //*************THE NEXT LINE CAUSES THE ERROR****************
        double quantity=sd.nextDouble();
        //Declaración e inicialización de métodos
        public void addTaberna(){
    System.out.print("Ingrese importe: ");
    while(quantity!=0){
        taberna.add(quantity);
    }
    System.out.print("El total consumido en esta categoría es de: ");
    Iterator <Double> itTaberna=taberna.iterator();
    while(itTaberna.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(itTaberna.next());
    }

}
public void addtPublico(){
    System.out.print("Ingrese importe: ");
    while(quantity!=0){
        tPublico.add(quantity);
    }
    Iterator <Double> itTPublico=tPublico.iterator();
    while(itTPublico.hasNext()){
        sumTPublico+=itTPublico.next();
    }
    System.out.println("Gastos totales en Transporte Público: " + sumTPublico);
                }
        public void addAlimentacion(){
            System.out.print("Ingrese importe: ");
            alimentacion.add(sd.nextDouble());
        }
        public void addFormacion(){
            System.out.print("Ingrese importe: ");
            formacion.add(sd.nextDouble());
        }
    }




//THIS IS THE DRIVER CLASS

package gestioneconomica;
import java.util.Scanner;


class GastosExe{
    public static void main(String[]args){

        System.out.println("###################################################");
        System.out.println("BIENVENIDO/A AL PROGRAMA DE GASTOS DE ROBIN");
        System.out.println("###################################################");
        System.out.println("(1)TABERNA\t(2)TRANSPORTE PÚBLICO\t(3)ALIMENTACIÓN\t (4)INVERSIÓN FORMATIVA"); 
        System.out.println("Seleccione el tipo de Gasto: ");

        Gastos gastos=new Gastos();
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);


        int tipo=sc.nextInt();
        switch(tipo){
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Ha seleccionado Taberna");
                gastos.addTaberna();

                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Ha seleccionado Transporte Público");

                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Ha seleccionado Alimentación");
                gastos.addAlimentacion();
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Ha seleccionado Inversión Formativa");
                gastos.addFormacion();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should select an accepted answer for your questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO. This is a very nicely phrased first question.

> at that moment the execution thread remains in Execution and it does
>   not return any type of error

That's because there is no error here. And the correct term is "at the moment the execution thread (main thread) remains **blocked**" Your program is behaving exactly the way you coded it to behave

Let's break it down from the main method.

```
Gastos gastos=new Gastos();
```

When you call the Gastos constructor here on the main method, the Gastos class initializes, which has the `quantity` field of type double, initialized directly with the input from the Scanner.

When execution reaches this line `double quantity = sd.nextDouble();` *it blocks the main thread*, waiting for keyboard input from the user..

So you should enter a selection here `1`

when you press enter, `sd.nextDouble();` method returns, and main thread resumes.

Then, when the Gastos() constructor call returns and the main thread reaches this line `int tipo = sc.nextInt();`

Which *blocks the main thread again*, waiting for another keyboard input from the user.

So you should enter a selection here again `2`

When you press enter, `sc.nextInt();` method returns and the main thread resumes execution

**Sample run**

```
###################################################
BIENVENIDO/A AL PROGRAMA DE GASTOS DE ROBIN
###################################################
(1)TABERNA  (2)TRANSPORTE PÚBLICO   (3)ALIMENTACIÓN  (4)INVERSIÓN FORMATIVA
Seleccione el tipo de Gasto: 
1
2
Ha seleccionado Transporte Público
```

Comment: Hi, don't forget to choose an accepted answer for your questions if you found the answer helpful (It's the check mark next to the answer below the vote buttons)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
double quantity = Double.parseDouble(sd.nextLine());
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still does not work. This is the output:                                                                     run-single:  
###################################################
BIENVENIDO/A AL PROGRAMA DE GASTOS DE ROBIN MANEIRO
###################################################
(1)TABERNA (2)TRANSPORTE PÚBLICO (3)ALIMENTACIÓN  (4)INVERSIÓN FORMATIVA
Seleccione el tipo de Gasto: 
1